# How can I verify that the fonts are all embedded in my LuaLatex document?

Tags: fonts, luatex, embedding

I am working with a manufacturer who is typically used to getting pdfs from more traditional Adobe tools, read: not LuaLatex. They are telling me to "make sure" that my fonts are embedded in the `.pdf` files I give them.

This particular link says that "lualatex always embeds fonts", but as glyphs.
It also talks about editing the `pdftex.map` to force the embedding of the entire font.  I had some trouble finding where that file even exists.  In `/etc?`
 [[Does lualatex embed fonts for compatibility?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66934/does-lualatex-embed-fonts-for-compatibility?rq=1][1])

At the end of the day, I am a Linux guy running `lualatex` on an Ubuntu machine.  I want to be able to tell my manufacturer "yes, file contains embedded fonts".  There is a little bit of a language barrier, so the more I can do on my end, the better.

Help?

How can I:

1. Make sure the pdf file contains the full embedded fonts?  Is there an inspection tool that shows this?
2. (or) What do I need to do to make this happen if `lualatex` isn't doing the right thing

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always use the pdffonts tool to see whether or not a font has been embedded into the pdf or is just being referred to. I think it might just be best to create a sample document and have them check the pdf, explaining that you do not have access to the Adobe tools being a Linux user.

Comment: you could use some validation tools like verapdf to perform checks and most viewers give basic feedback e.g  evince and ocular viewers should give some info via file properties

Comment: If there’s a language barrier, you might want to clarify what the requirement is, and what isn’t working on their end.

Comment: @daleif what is the meaning of "a font is just being referred to"? Thank you!

Comment: @manooooh not empedded. The pdf will say use font x, but there will be no copy of the font in the pdf. The viewer will the either get the fonts from the system fonts (latex fonts are useally not included) or it will substitute the font leading to strafe results. Thus we to not want fonts that are not embedded.

Answer (score 5):

To embed complete fonts you have to set the embedding mode to `full` rather than the default `subset`.  You can do this in the `patch_font` callback of `luaotfload`.  Be aware that most commercial fonts do not allow full embedding but only subset embedding in their license.  You also have to reload your fonts, otherwise the callback doesn't fire.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
local function embedfull(tfmdata)
    tfmdata.embedding = "full"
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("luaotfload.patch_font", embedfull, "embedfull")
\end{luacode}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}

Hello World!

\end{document}
```

```
$ pdffonts test.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
LMRoman10-Regular                    CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes no  yes      4  0
```

Answer (score 4):

Your system most likely has `pdffonts` (or you could obtain it) running `pdffonts` on a typical luatex output produces

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
SJYSYS+TeXGyreTermes-Regular-Identity-H CID Type 0C       Identity-H    yes yes yes     5  0
LOMGHQ+TeXGyreTermesMath-Regular-Identity-H CID Type 0C   Identity-H    yes yes yes     7  0
```

Note the `yes` in the `emb` column denoting embedded fonts.

Comment: Doesn't the `yes` in the `sub` column indicate that only a subset is included whereas the OP seems to want full embedding?